# Is there a default location for 'linux too applications'

Tags: folders, defaults

I recently moved to OS X from Windows 7. In Windows, pretty much everything gets installed to `C:\Program Files\[application name]` or `C:\[application name]`. In OS X `/Applications` seems to be roughly equivalent to `C:\Program Files` for all the consumer apps that I use.

But when it comes to a 'linux too' application (e.g. Python, Postgres, Node JS to name just a few) they seem to get installed *all over the place*. Only after spending a few minutes guessing and using `find` did I discover that Postgres executables were installed to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/`, v8 and Node were in `/usr/local/bin`. Often times these differ to the equivalent paths that I see Linux users refer to.

Is there a better way to discover where my apps are being installed than by having to use `find` each time? Shouldn't I be able to predict it with rules of thumb something like 'all database apps should go in `/Library`' so that's where I know to look for postgres, and 'all compilers and languages go in `/usr/local/bin`' so that's where I know to look for v8 after it's installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, unfortunately, no there isn't a default location.

But it's not complete chaos.

For command line tools that ship with the OS or get brought in by Apple-supplied applications like Xcode, you'll find it all in `/usr/bin`. That includes things like the OS X default Python and Perl as well as the Xcode-supplied `gcc`, `clang`, `make` and the other command line developer tools Xcode installs.

For non-Apple command line tools, if the application is well-behaved, it should put them in `/usr/local/bin`.

Some `.app` packaged applications that install under `/Applications` offer command line tools (for example `subl` offered by Sublime Text 2). If I want to use these from the command line I'll generally make a symlink from `/usr/local/bin` to the tool under the `.app` file for the application rather than put the application-specific path on my `PATH` environment variable.

If you use a package manager like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install and manage your command line tools then it's not too much of a hardship to make `/usr/local/bin` the place for everything you use. Homebrew does a very nice job of keeping it neat and clean and all in one place for you. I can't speak to how well MacPorts or Fink keep things contained under one sub-tree like this.

The exception to the rules are OS X-default daemons like Postgres and such. Those can get scattered and there really isn't a very good way to track them down aside from `find` and maybe `mdfind` from the command line.